# Clear a matplolib via button

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I got 2 functions to get the values of the HDD drives. I am using tkinter and I can access the graphics with the buttons. But, after I click on one, I can't seem to remove the previous.

```
The objective is: if I click the "C Drive" button, I erase the E graph, and if I click on the "E" drive, I erase the C graph.

#Disk E Storage
def hdd_e():
    usage_e=shutil.disk_usage("E:\\")
    total_space_e = usage_e[0]
    used_space_e = usage_e[1]
    free_space_e =usage_e[2]
    fig_e = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(50, 5), facecolor="#F0F0F0")
    canvas_e = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig_e, master=tab3)
    ax_e = fig_e.add_subplot(111)
    ax_e.pie([total_space_e, used_space_e, free_space_e])
    ax_e.legend(["Total", "Used", "Free"])
    circle_e = matplotlib.patches.Circle((0, 0), 0)
    ax_e.add_artist(circle_e)
    canvas_e.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas_e.draw()


#Disk C Storage
def hdd_c():
    usage_c=shutil.disk_usage("C:\\")
    total_space_c = usage_c[0]
    used_space_c = usage_c[1]
    free_space_c =usage_c[2]
    fig_c = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(50, 5), facecolor="#F0F0F0")
    canvas_c = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig_c, master=tab3)
    ax_c = fig_c.add_subplot(111)
    ax_c.pie([total_space_c, used_space_c, free_space_c ])
    ax_c.legend(["Total", "Used", "Free"])
    circle_c = matplotlib.patches.Circle((0, 0), 0)
    ax_c.add_artist(circle_c)
    canvas_c.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas_c.draw()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544881/show-matplotlib-figure-in-canvas/65547625#65547625

Comment: Kinda, the problem is that it destroys everything on the screen, including buttons. I will try to mess around with the code to see what I can do. Thanks. Ill post an update.

Comment: I have added an edit there, check that out again, you'll get more info there. If you just want to destroy the math plot canvas use `FigureCanvasTkAgg.get_tk_widget().destroy()`